# Is a SQL Constraint On Multiple Columns and Values Possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and have a table `ProjectAccess` which I'm hoping to use as a way to "lock" access to Projects. Currently the table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectAccess] 
(
    [ProjectAccessID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] INT NOT NULL,
    [UserSessionID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Locked] BIT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [uq_UserSessionID] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([UserSessionID]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_ProjectAccessToProject] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Project] ([ProjectID]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [fk_ProjectAccessToUserSession] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserSessionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserSession] ([UserSessionID]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProjectAccess] 
        PRIMARY KEY ([ProjectAccessID])
);
```

The idea was to only allow for multiple of the same project ID's into this table, but only one could have the `Locked` column value as true. For example you could have two records with `ProjectID` 1 in the table at the same time as long as both did not have the Locked value set to true. So is there a way to do this? I see that there is a check constraint but that seems to check all values in a column satisfy a certain condition which is a little different than what I'm hoping for. Thank you in advance and let me know if anything isn't clear enough.

Comment: Whoever downvoted please explain why instead of being useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_projectaccess_projectid_locked
    on projectaccess(projectid)
    where locked = 1;
```